# Round to The Nearest within PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery

How to **round** to the **nearest**;

For example formular we use **ceiling(10,30)** within excel which would give us **30**, how do we do that within **PowerQuery** to get the same results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number.Round()

Full details here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/number-round

Additional Info as you've mentioned Round in the Subject and problem detail, but then used Ceiling as well.  I don't think Ceiling exists in M, so you will have to use some extra math such as the following.

```
(Number.RoundUp([number]/30))*30
```

In the above formula, [number] is your starting number and 30 represents the significance.  On some test data:

- 22.2 becomes 30
- 44 becomes 60
- 91 becomes 120

Comment: Guess I should have asked for clarification as the subject of the question is 'Round' and the question starts with "How to round...".  I'll update my answer with some extra info as I don't think Ceiling exists in M.